# "4 hours each session" or "each session will last for 4 hours"

Tags: syntax, construction

Which one is clearer and grammatically correct?

> 1. The course will commence on December 2 every Mondays and Wednesday, 4 hours each session, for 4 weeks
> 2. The course will be scheduled every Mondays and Wednesdays starting on December 2, which will be for 4 weeks; each session will last for 4 hours.
> 3. This 4-week course will start on December 2 and each session runs for 4 hours every Mondays and Wednesdays.

---

I have a follow-up question:

> 1 The course will start on December 2 and *will run for 4 weeks with 4-hour session every Monday and Wednesday
>
> 2 The course will start on December 2 and *run(s?) for 4 weeks with 4-hour session every Monday and Wednesday

Comment: The meaning is clear, which is good news,  but both sentences are verbose and awkward-sounding and need to be rewritten.

Comment: @KillingTime, I have edited my construction.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Don't use a big word where a diminutive one would do.

Comment: Added a 3rd sentence... BTW it's "every Monday", we say "every day" NOT "every days"

Answer (score 2):

You could say

> The course will start on December 2nd and run for 4 weeks with 4 hour sessions every Monday and Wednesday.

or even

> The 4 week course will start on 2nd December. 4 hour sessions will be every Monday and Wednesday.

Maybe breaking the original into two simpler sentences will make it clearer.

---

Since writing the above, you have added version 3

> This 4-week course will start on December 2 and each session runs for 4 hours every Mondays and Wednesdays.

Which contains a minor error. You can either say

> ...each session runs for 4 hours every Monday and Wednesday.

or

> each session runs for 4 hours **on** Mondays and Wednesdays.

---

Regarding your additional questions, minor corrections again

> 1 The course will start on December 2 and will run for 4 weeks with 4-hour **sessions** every Monday and Wednesday

or

> 1 The course will start on December 2 and *will run for 4 weeks with **a** 4-hour session every Monday and Wednesday

and similarly

> 2 The course will start on December 2 and **runs** for 4 weeks with 4-hour **sessions** every Monday and Wednesday

or

> 2 The course will start on December 2 and **runs** for 4 weeks with **a** 4-hour session every Monday and Wednesday

However, as Mary and I have already pointed out, it would be better to simplify your sentence, possibly in the way I originally proposed - break it into 2 shorter ones with one idea in each.

Comment: Thank you for your help and for pointing out my mistakes.

Comment: I have a follow-up question: #1 The course will start on December 2 and *will run for 4 weeks with 4-hour session every Monday and Wednesday  #2 The course will start on December 2 and *run(s?) for 4 weeks with 4-hour session every Monday and Wednesday.

Comment: @Hydes I have taken the liberty to edit you original question to add these sentences.